# Simplest way to sum 2D array elements based on duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

So say I have a 2D array. Maybe something like:

```
data = [['oct 1', 4], ['oct 2', 5], ['oct 3', 9], ['oct 1', 2]]
```

And I want to get a new array out of this, that removes the duplicate values (eg. oct 1), but sums the corresponding values.

So I would end up with:

```
data = (['oct 1', 6], ['oct 2', 5], ['oct 3', 9])
```

I can think of a few ways to do this but they seem pretty inefficent and usually there's always some crazy ruby code that can do anything in a few lines, any suggestions?

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. Without that evidence of effort it looks like you want us to do the work you're supposed to have done. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways of doing that, my preference being the first.

**Use a *counting hash***

*Code*

```
def combine(data)
  data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(date, val), h| h[date] += val }.to_a
end
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), the discussion of the default value in particular.

*Example*

```
data = [['oct 1', 4], ['oct 2', 5], ['oct 3', 9], ['oct 1', 2]]
combine data 
  #=> [["oct 1", 6], ["oct 2", 5], ["oct 3", 9]]
```

*Explanation*

```
enum = data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["oct 1", 4], ["oct 2", 5], ["oct 3", 9],
  #                  ["oct 1", 2]]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the values generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[["oct 1", 4], {}], [["oct 2", 5], {}], [["oct 3", 9], {}],
  #    [["oct 1", 2], {}]]
```

The first value of `enum` is passed to the block and the values of the block variables are computed, using *disambiguation* and *parallel assignment*.

```
(date, val), h = enum.next
  #=> [["oct 1", 4], {}] 
date
  #=> "oct 1"      
val
  #=> 4

h[date] += val
  #=> h[date] = h[date] + val
  #=> h["oct 1"] = h["oct 1"] + 4
  #=> h["oct 1"] = 0 + 4 (no key "oct 1" so default value of `0` used)
  #=> h["oct 1"] = 4
```

Now,

```
h #=> {"oct 1"=>4}
```

The remaining three values of `enum` are passed to the block and the block calculations are performed.

```
(date, val), h = enum.next
  #=> [["oct 2", 5], {"oct 1"=>4}]
h[date] += val 
  #=> 5 (the default value of `0` is again used)
h #=> {"oct 1"=>4, "oct 2"=>5} 

(date, val), h = enum.next
  #=> [["oct 3", 9], {"oct 1"=>4, "oct 2"=>5}] 
h[date] += val
  #=> 9 (the default value of `0` is again used)
h #=> {"oct 1"=>4, "oct 2"=>5, "oct 3"=>9} 

(date, val), h = enum.next
  #=> [["oct 1", 2], {"oct 1"=>4, "oct 2"=>5, "oct 3"=>9}] 
h[date] += val
  #=> 6 
h #=> {"oct 1"=>6, "oct 2"=>5, "oct 3"=>9}
```

In the last calculation, the default value was not used because the hash `h` already had a key `"oct 1"`:

```
h[date] += val
  #=> h[date] = h[date] + val
  #=> h["oct 1"] = h["oct 1"] + 2
  #=> h["oct 1"] = 4 + 2
```

Lastly,

```
h.to_a
  #=> [["oct 1", 6], ["oct 2", 5], ["oct 3", 9]]
```

**Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

*Code*

```
def combine(data) 
  data.group_by(&:first).map { |date, vals| [date, vals.map(&:last).reduce(:+)] }
end
```

*Example*

```
combine data 
  #=> [["oct 1", 6], ["oct 2", 5], ["oct 3", 9]]
```

*Explanation*

The steps:

```
h = data.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"oct 1"=>[["oct 1", 4], ["oct 1", 2]],
  #    "oct 2"=>[["oct 2", 5]], "oct 3"=>[["oct 3", 9]]}
```

The first key-value pair of `h` is passed to the block:

```
date, vals = h.first
  #=> ["oct 1", [["oct 1", 4], ["oct 1", 2]]] 
date
  #=> "oct 1" 
vals
  #=> [["oct 1", 4], ["oct 1", 2]]
```

and the block calculation is performed.

```
a = vals.map(&:last)
  #=> [4, 2] 
t = a.reduce(:+)
  #=> 6
```

So the first key-value pair of `h` is mapped to

```
[date, t]
  #=> ["oct 1", 6]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. As for my code formatting, I'm new to the site so I thought just a pseudo implementation would be OK, my bad!

Comment: Any tips on how to generalize this onto for example a 4D array?

Comment: That would depend on what the array would look like. For example, would the same key be present at different "levels"? Best to post a separate question (with an example).

Answer (score 0):

Try following with `inject` method:

```
data = [["oct 1", 4], ["oct 2", 5], ["oct 3", 9], ["oct 1", 2]]
data.inject({}) { |sum, (n, t)| sum[n] ||= 0; sum[n] += t; sum }.to_a
=> [["oct 1", 6], ["oct 2", 5], ["oct 3", 9]]
```